# Can I play Nintendo Switch in a country where I don't buy?

Tags: region-lock, nintendo-switch

I'm definitely going to purchase the Nintendo Switch. However, I travel all year round and thus wonder if it can be played in a country where I don't buy it.

In the case of the Nintendo 3DS, you can bring it to a different country and play there just by purchasing an adapter adjusted for the universal use (100-240V). I purchased it in China, where the 3DS was not released by Nintendo but it worked without any problems.

But the Nintendo Switch is considered a console for the home use. So I wonder if it is possible to play it in another country. Also, can I play it only as a handheld device or also as a console connected to the TV?

I asked this to Nintendo customer support but have not got any response.

Comment: The title seems unclear for me. What do you mean by 'where I don't buy' ? Like : Switchs are different from one country to another ? Or is the Switch compatible with the hardware of a country where they don't sell it ?
Could you change your title so people aren't misunderstood when reading your text after ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the Nintendo Switch region locked?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/301952/is-the-nintendo-switch-region-locked)

Comment: @Jutschge Why is this a duplicate? I don't ask if it is a region-locked

Comment: Hmm yeah I see it. I'll retract the close vote but I'll definitely keep my downvote... Display cables are the same in every country and you've figured out the part about the converter yourself. What's the point in asking?

Comment: @Jutschge In 3DS you can obtain universal adapters like [the following](https://www.amazon.com/Adapter-New-3DS-2DS-DSi-Nintendo/dp/B008MIGV1E), which is compatible with 100V to 240V(or 245V). But this is not true of Switch.

Comment: This sounds more like "can I charge my Switch in another country?" There's no reason you couldn't 'play' it in another country

Answer (score 6):

**You can use the Switch in any country you like.**

Depending on where you buy the switch you get a different plug for the charger(Note: That part that goes into the switch is always the same). If you plan on traveling a lot you would need a different charger, or better a **adapter** to plug it into the local electricity network. [Something like this.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000YN01X4)

WIFI is standardized so there should be no problems.

Connection to the TV is via HDMI, so only thing there would be the need for an HDMI Port on the TV/Screen. Not completly sure about this one but i think there are no other factors to consider.

Comment: Isn't it true that because different countries use different voltages, the adapter I purchased in Japan doesn't work in Europe, right? The linked adapter is only let you connect one type of outlet to another, right?

Answer (score 4):

The nintendo switch is not region locked - so you can buy whatever imported game you like.

([Source](https://twitter.com/NintendoAmerica/status/819757062586593280))

Comment: I don't ask if it is region-locked nor if any game is playable in a console that is purchased in another country. I asked if a console itself is playable in another country.

Comment: Of course you can, why wouldn't you? I have never heard of any device where you couldn't play a english game with an english console in foreign countries. (beside compatibility issues like PAL & NTSC). Just be careful where you setup your eShop as you might only get full service and support in that country: http://www.siliconera.com/2017/01/20/nintendo-switch-will-let-8-accounts-country-based-eshop/

Comment: But isn't the plug different? So how can I play it?

Comment: Why should the plug be dependend on how you play it? The switch comes with your regional equivalent AC-Adapter to USB-C adapter. If you go abroad, you need either another adapter or an AC-Converter, but this should be the same problem you have with your Nintendo 3DS. So I kinda don't understand your question anymore.

Comment: As said by @Christian it's not a matter about the Switch, but then it only become a matter of : you need an adapter for different plug (as you would for any of your others hardware), and I don't know that much about TVs nowadays but are they still different ? (such as their frequencies ?).
So it has nothing to do with the Switch. Just you taking care of buying the good adapters for all your hardware and checking compatibility with the TVs you're going to have (but at worst you'll only have to play on the Switch directly) ... Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a full-fledged converter. The power is compatible with ALL power systems. All you need is an adapter so you can fit it into the wall socket (Like trying to use a U.S./Japan plug in Hong Kong, Singapore, or Australia...)

e-shop access from any region to any other region is in no way limited. Unless you're in a place like North Korea that may block public access to internet from foreign countries...

And TV output is via HDMI, so you don't need to worry about PAL/NTSC. It's already compatible with both.